# RODBC connection from R to SQL failing

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I'm using R Studio to connect to SQL Server Management using `library(RODBC)`.

Note that the below code works on my local system, but does not work when trying to connect remotely.

This is my connection code:

```
connection <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(   'driver={SQL Server};server=SERVERNAME ;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=TRUE' )
```

I get the following warning message:

```
Warning messages:

1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SERVERNAME;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=TRUE") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 18, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SERVERNAME;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=TRUE") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 772, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).
3: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=SERVERNAME;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=TRUE") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

It's really odd because I definitely have access to the server and database in question.

It's worth noting that I have access to the server from a local system (above code works) and access to a remote system (code does not work).

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: No that hasn't worked unfortunately @knb

Comment: maybe your windows firewall blocks incoming connections on port 1433 but allows them from localhost.

Comment: Hmm okay. I'm not sure there's anything I can do about that is there?

Answer (score 0):

`RODBC` is not a great package, it would be much better to use the RStudio built `odbc` instead:

```
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server", 
                 Server = "SERVER",
                 Database = "DATABASE",
                 Trusted_Connection = "True" ,
                 timeout = 5000
)
```

Comment: That hasn't worked either. it just seems to run for ages but doesn't time out (I left it for about 30 mins). Good to know about odbc though

Answer (score -1):

In the following command line
`connection <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(   'driver={SQL Server};server=SERVERNAME ;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=TRUE' )`

make trusted_connection = FALSE or no. Its a simple case of SSL error. If you are using linux, for server, use ip address rather than hostname.

Comment: I've tried changing the true connection to false (see above). Also not sure what you mean by changing the host name to the ip address, where would I do that?

Comment: like this `odbcDriverConnect('driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;server=196.1.1.1;uid=user;pwd=password;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=no')`